# Threads - output desincronizado

Tags: java

¿Que diferencia hay entre el primer y segundo código? ¿Porque, viendo el primero, los output me salen desordenados o repetidos y en el segundo salen bien?
En el primero, el método syncronizado es el de ´Persona´, y teniendo la misma instancia para los dos threads,no entiendo porque salen mal o repetidos los outputs.

```
 public class Main {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                BolsaPersonas bolsa = new BolsaPersonas();

                Thread thread = new Thread(bolsa);
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(bolsa);
                thread.start();
                thread2.start();


            }

        }

        class BolsaPersonas implements Runnable {

            Persona persona = new Persona();

            @Override
            public void run() {
                incrementar();
            }

            public synchronized void incrementar() {
                for (int i=0;i<5000;i++) {
                    persona.doStuff();
                }
            }


        }

        class Persona {

            private int id = 1;
            private Object objeto = new Object();


            public void doStuff() {
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ID: " + id);
                id++;
            }

        }




    class BolsaPersonas implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Persona persona = new Persona();

            for (int i=0;i<5000;i++) {
                persona.doStuff();
            }

        }


    }

    class Persona {

        private int id = 1;
        private Object objeto = new Object();


        public synchronized void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ID: " + id);
            id++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Trata de formatear el código mejor, el exceso de líneas en blanco hace más dificil leerlo. Además, los dos códigos no se distinguen bien (hay una sola clase Main y las inner classes están repetidas ). La idea es que uno pueda copiar y pegar el código y que ande...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiqué los códigos para hacerlo más claro, a ver si entendí tu problema.

Primer código (sincronizando en `BolsaPersonas.incrementar`) :

```
public class NoMezclaThreads {

    static class BolsaPersonas implements Runnable {
        Persona persona = new Persona();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            incrementar();
        }

        public synchronized void incrementar() {
            for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                persona.doStuff();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Persona {
        private int id = 1;

        public   void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ID: " + id);
            id++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BolsaPersonas bolsa = new BolsaPersonas();
        Thread thread = new Thread(bolsa);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(bolsa);
        thread.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 1
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 2
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 3
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 4
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 5
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 6
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 7
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 8
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 9
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 10
```

Segundo código (idéntico, excepto que sincroniza en `Persona.doStuff`) :

```
public class MezclaThreads {

    static class BolsaPersonas implements Runnable {
        Persona persona = new Persona();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            incrementar();
        }

        public void incrementar() {
            for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                persona.doStuff();
            }
        }
    }

    static class Persona {
        private int id = 1;

        public synchronized  void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". ID: " + id);
            id++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BolsaPersonas bolsa = new BolsaPersonas();
        Thread thread = new Thread(bolsa);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(bolsa);
        thread.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 1
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 2
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 3
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 4
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 5
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 6
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 7
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 8
Thread: Thread-0. ID: 9
Thread: Thread-1. ID: 10
```

¿Qué está pasando aquí? Cuando sincronizas en un método, estás adquiriendo un lock sobre el objeto al cual el método pertenece (como sincronizar sobre `this`). Y le estás diciendo a Java: *"te prohibo que otro thread ejecute ningún método de **este objeto**" hasta que haya terminado con este método"*.

En el primer caso (`NoMezclaThreads`), como hay un solo objeto `BolsaPersonas` instanciado, y como el método sincronizado pertenece a este único objeto, el sincronismo funciona así: cuando el segundo thread quiere correr este método se encuentra conque el objeto está "lockeado" por el primer thread, y se queda esperando hasta que termina.

En el segundo caso, el sincronismo funciona sólo al nivel del método `doStuff` (nunca habrá dos threads ejecutando este método al mismo tiempo) pero como los dos threads están en paralelo el método `incrementar` se repartirán entre ellos la ejecución.

En ningún caso deberían imprimirse id duplicados, por lo que veo.

Comment: Mmmm ami en el primer ejemplo me salía desordenado o repetido, lo que quiere decir que el lock no funcionaba bien por algún motivo.